# Can an app have dashboard menu as a first screen?

Tags: navigation, dashboard, tab-bar

I'm designing an app for pharmacists and their clients. The app holds many options and the pharmacists would like their clients to compose their own menu. For now i have a tabbar menu with 3 options and a more option which opens up a list view of the other options.

My question is:

- Can I present the user with the list view as the first screen?
- If so, the tabbar is also visible but which menu option should be enabled? I assume the 'more' option but it seems strange to highlight the 'more' option as last one in the tabbar on opening the app. It feels like the first one in the tabbar is usually highlighted.
- I have a discrepancy here with the navigation bar, I don't quite know which label it should have + it has the profile and  notification option visible, while they are no longer visible when a user clicks on the 'more' option later on. Because normally the user then only needs a 'cancel' option to close the list view

Any feedback is welcome. Thx

[image]

Comment: why do clients need to compose their own menu? Does this mean making new pages? What are 1) your business goals, 2) the pharmacists goals, and 3) the clients goals? It seems like a burden to compose a menu, but who are the 'clients'? Are they individual consumers?

Comment: You could add a home icon and have that enabled or just not have any tab bar icons enabled.

Comment: some clients need options more than others and thus having them in their tabbar makes it easier to access. It's not mant for making new pages, just for accessing those screens. Clients are indeed individual customers

Comment: I would look at the definition and common use of dashboards to make sure that your implementation matches with user expectations... but of course you can do anything with the user interface as long as it is logical and user friendly - and the best way to know is by doing some testing :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, if you think it is useful.
2. Then the tabbar should probably have a tab for your dashboard. Let's name it Dashboard or Home (no, it's a bad idea).
3. It looks a bit overcomplicated. Are you sure you need Profile circle to be shown all the time? The app looks like a phone app, and users usually don't pass their phones to other people (and they know how their own face looks like, from the mirror). Why not to put Profile deeper into the More?

Why do you always need a bell of notifications? It looks like you wanna notify people a lot. And users are supposed to read your notifications. What if they turned off their notifications – the Bell will still keep its place occupied?

My advice would be: have not an abstract place for all Notifications, but more precise one. Like Medications, Prescriptions, you probably have the needed items at your Dashboard. Put your notifications there. Let user know what kind of notification they have. Don't let yourself to create an offtopic spam notification by having the abstract junkbox of All Kinds of Notifications. Generally, I believe that the Bell menu is as anti-pattern as Hamburger menu.

Sorry for being such a lecturer.

Answer (score 1):

With this design direction you are following a desktop homepage pattern of hotspots/cards and left nav that take you to the same place.  This works as long as your cards can give you high level information that is relevant to the user. If you have no way of doing this, then hide the tab nav at the bottom until the user has made their first selection. Then bring up the tabbed footer so that they can continue to move through the application without having to go back to the landing page each time.

Also badging each card and your tabs would be needed to keep notifications contextual from both locations.  I agree with Sergey that having a notification bucket is generally a bad idea.